# MYSQL column containing % symbol

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping

I am trying to create a table with a the column name `aggregate_report_90%_line` in mysql. I am getting a syntax error because of the `%` symbol. How do I create a column with `%` symbol?

Comment: Don't use symbols as column names, it will cause trouble all the time

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape it with \% . But it is not a good style. Avoid it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

You should avoid it because '%' is a special symbol which can be used in [select queries as a wildcard](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/like.php).

Comment: I tried escaping, but it still wont work. aggregate_report_90\%_line did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should always qoute it with backticks:

```
`aggregate_report_90%_line`
```